# Performance for empty function call vs defensive coding

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I am currently building a React component (below) which may or may not have an onChange prop passed down to it from it's parent.

At the moment, I am checking whether an onChange prop is passed down, and then firing it if it is, i.e. if(this.props.onChange) {this.props.onChange()}

I am wondering whether this is better or worse from a performance perspective, than just firing the onChange event, even if it's not passed down from the parent, i.e. firing an empty function without the if(this.props.onChange) condition.

Would appreciate any insight into this

***Component***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class SelectBox extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    selectOptions: PropTypes.array,
    onChange: PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '';
    }
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });

    if(this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {this.onChange(e)}} >

        {this.props.selectOptions.map(option => (
          <option 
            key={option.key}
            value={option.value}
            disabled={option.disabled}>
                {option.text}
          </option>
        ))}

      </select>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: It is almost certainly faster to not call the function, though I doubt the performance difference would be noticeable either way

Comment: Yea i didn't think it would be a massive difference, just curious on the answer really to settle a discussion

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you wouldn't be firing an empty function; this.props.onChange would be undefined, so you would get an error saying this.props.onChange is not a function.

Comment: @MichaelHorn *sigh...*

Comment: @KevinB Am I wrong?

Comment: i mean, obviously the op is asking about using a noop function ("empty function") vs a conditional to not call a function at all

Comment: @KevinB The way I understood it, op is just talking about removing the conditional, in which case there would be no distinguishing when he should fire this.props.onChange, vs an empty function. Without a conditional, it must be the same call every time, and the only call that would be logical to make is the one passed down in the props. Otherwise, you would never do anything with the onChange event.

Answer (score 0):

An empty function call does not cost much, don't over-optimize, just improve the bottlenecks, such as :

- DOM API calls (handled by react)
- heavy computation, loops, big array operations (you're not doing any here)